# How could the contents of multiple LastPass vaults be compromised?

Tags: password-management, exploit, data-leakage, cloud-storage, lastpass

According to this newly published [article](https://www.makeuseof.com/change-passwords-after-lastpass-data-breach/):

> Now, it appears that the LastPass hack has led cybercriminals to steal over $35 million in cryptocurrencies.
>
> ...
>
> Nick Bax, director of analytics at Unciphered, has been reviewing a huge quantity crypto theft data unearthed by Metamask's Taylor Monahan and other researchers. In September 2023, he told KrebsonSecurity that criminals had moved crypto "from multiple victims to the same blockchain addresses, making it possible to strongly link those victims."
>
> After identifying and interviewing victims, he concluded that the only common factor was that they used LastPass to store their crypto seed phrases.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LastPass), LastPass vaults use the following encryption techniques:

> Information is encrypted with AES-256 encryption with PBKDF2 SHA-256, salted hashes, and the ability to increase password iterations value. Encryption and decryption takes place at the device level.

Given that level of encryption, how could the contents of multiple LastPass vaults be compromised by the 2022 LastPass hack and data breach?

Or is the author of the article likely jumping to an erroneous conclusion by claiming the hack has something to do with the losses experienced by the cryptocurrency theft victims?

Comment: See "Offline Attacks" in [Experts Fear Crooks are Cracking Keys Stolen in LastPass Breach](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2023/09/experts-fear-crooks-are-cracking-keys-stolen-in-lastpass-breach/) and [LastPass breach: The significance of these password iterations](https://palant.info/2022/12/28/lastpass-breach-the-significance-of-these-password-iterations/).